# How to Get Button Position defined in FXML File from java class

Tags: java, button, javafx-2, fxml

I created with javafx scene builder the fxml file for the interface.
Now I need to get the button position on the interface but when I call the button method to get the X,Y coord, the value returned is 0.0.

FXML code:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.NewInvoceController">
<children>  
<VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
        <HBox prefHeight="153.0" prefWidth="1161.0">
           <children>
              <GridPane fx:id="invoiceCustomerGrid" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="514.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                </rowConstraints>
                 <children>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <children>
                          <Label fx:id="customerManager" onMouseClicked="#openCustomerWin" text="Ragione Sociale/Cognome Nome">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <TextField prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="223.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets />
                             </HBox.margin></TextField>
                          <Button fx:id="customerButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openCustomerList" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="20.0" text="B" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                          </Button>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                       <children>
                          <Label text="P.I.">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <TextField HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </TextField>
                          <Label text="C.F.">
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <TextField HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </TextField>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                       <children>
                          <Label text="Indirizzo" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <TextField HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </TextField>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="516.0" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                       <children>
                          <Label text="Cap">
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <TextField minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="60.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </TextField>
                          <Label text="Città">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <TextField HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                          </TextField>
                          <Label text="Provincia">
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <TextField minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="30.0">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </TextField>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox spacing="5.0">
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </padding>
                       <children>
                          <Label text="Fattura N°">
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <TextField prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="58.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                          </TextField>
                          <Label text="Data">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </Label>
                          <DatePicker prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="123.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                          </DatePicker>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
              </GridPane>
              <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" />
              <GridPane fx:id="invoiceMoreGrid" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="640.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="140.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                </rowConstraints>
                 <children>
                    <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Oggetto" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Button>
                          <TextField HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </HBox.margin>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </TextField>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <children>
                          <VBox prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="100.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <children>
                                <HBox prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="319.0">
                                   <children>
                                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pagamento">
                                         <HBox.margin>
                                            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                         </HBox.margin>
                                         <font>
                                            <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                                         </font>
                                      </Button>
                                   </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <TextArea prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="310.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                                   <VBox.margin>
                                      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                   </VBox.margin></TextArea>
                             </children>
                          </VBox>
                          <VBox prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="100.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <children>
                                <HBox prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="319.0">
                                   <children>
                                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Note" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                                         <HBox.margin>
                                            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                         </HBox.margin>
                                         <font>
                                            <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                                         </font>
                                      </Button>
                                   </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <TextArea prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="310.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                                   <VBox.margin>
                                      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                   </VBox.margin></TextArea>
                             </children>
                          </VBox>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
              </GridPane>
           </children>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
        <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
        <HBox prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="1055.0">
           <children>
              <Label text="Cod.">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <TextField prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="110.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
              </TextField>
              <Label text="Descr.">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <TextField HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
              </TextField>
              <Label text="Prz. Un.">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <TextField prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="95.0">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </TextField>
              <Label text="Qta.">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <TextField prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="46.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
              </TextField>
              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Button>
           </children>
        </HBox>
        <TableView prefHeight="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
          <columns>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="115.0" text="Codice" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="697.0" text="Descrizione" />
              <TableColumn prefWidth="130.0" text="Prz. Un." />
              <TableColumn prefWidth="63.0" text="Qta" />
              <TableColumn prefWidth="106.0" text="Tot. Imp." />
              <TableColumn prefWidth="58.0" text="\% Iva" />
          </columns>
        </TableView>
        <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
        <GridPane>
          <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          </rowConstraints>
           <children>
       ....
```

JAVA Code

```java
public class NewInvoceController extends Window implements Initializable,ChangeListener<Boolean> {
    
    @FXML
    Label customerManager;
    
    @FXML
    Button customerButton;
    
    @FXML
    ListView<String> listCustomer;
     
    @FXML
    VBox vobxNewInvoce;
    
    Popup popup;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        focusedProperty().addListener(this);
        assert customerButton != null : "fx:id=\"customerButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'simple.fxml'.";
        System.out.println("PARENT" + customerButton.getLayoutX()); 
    }
    
    
    public void openCustomerList(ActionEvent event){
        
    
         CustomPopUpWindowsList popup = new CustomPopUpWindowsList(((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow(),customerButton);
         popup.newCustomPopUpWindowsList();
        
    }
    
    public void openCustomerWin(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/GUI/fxml/customer.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("My New Stage Title");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            stage.initOwner(((Node)(mouseEvent.getSource())).getScene().getWindow());
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();
            
            //hide this current window (if this is whant you want
            //((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
            Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        
        if (newValue)
        {
            System.out.println("Textfield on focus");
           
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Textfield out focus");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and thanks for the reply. 
I solved it with the following code.

```
Button bt;

Bounds localBounds = bt.localToScene(bt.getBoundsInLocal());

double popupX = bt.getScene().getWindow().getX() + localBounds.getMaxX();
double popupY = bt.getScene().getWindow().getY() + localBounds.getMaxY();
```

I hope that code can be helpful to others.